Condition always false PORTG
I am trying to compile this code and I'm getting a WARNING and an ERROR. I'm using PIC-C Compiler. I'm using a PIC24FJ256GA410. I have an LED at pin G0 and I have a pull-up resistor at pin G13. Why would i be getting this error?
I expected for that loop to keep running until PIN 13 was low (removed replaced pull-up resistor with a pull-down resistor).
Compiling C:\Users\uslucas1\OneDrive - ABB\Documents\CCS C Projects\testing port on 14-Nov-24 at 12:44
>>> Warning 204 "C:\Users\uslucas1\OneDrive - ABB\Documents\CCS C Projects\testing port.c" Line 11(1,1): Condition always FALSE   PORTG
*** Error 12 "C:\Users\uslucas1\OneDrive - ABB\Documents\CCS C Projects\testing port.c" Line 11(20,21): Undefined identifier
      1 Errors,  1 Warnings.

#include "24FJ256GA410.h"

#define PORTG_TRIS   set_tris_g(0xE008)         // All pins are output except G3, G13-15
outputs low

#define MVI_SELECT   (PORTG & 0x2000)           // Check if bit 13 of PORTG is high

void main()
{
  PORTG_TRIS;  // Set direction of PORTG pins
  
  while(MVI_SELECT)
  {
    output_high(PIN_G0);  // Set PIN_G0 high
  }

}


Is it a typo that there is a newline in front of "outputs low" in that source?

It also says "Undefined identifier" for the same line. Is PORTG defined? If so, what is its definition?

The diagnostics are about PORTG in the expansion of macro MVI_SELECT.  Without any information about that symbol, there's not much we can tell you beyond what the diagnostics already say.

Aside: this style of programming using pointless preprocessor macros is really horrible. It means that whenever you see something opaque like PORTG_TRIS in the code, you then have to go look for the definition of it. Don't do it, it's a bad habit to get into, and makes your life worse.

What is thisoutputs low? Don't look like standard c.

It can't find PORTG. Meaning that the register map isn't correct or it wasn't correctly linked. Are you sure that #include "24FJ256GA410.h" results in something meaningful? What does example code from Microchip look like? Can you view the actual header and find PORTG there?

Also make it a habit of using u suffix on all integer constants. On your 8/16 bit MCU 0x7FFF will result in signed int and 0x8000 and above will result in unsigned int. That's really brittle and you never want anything but unsigned int in this case.
